# Redefine cookie domain for subdomains

Tags: wp-config, subdomains, cookies

I have done all the research on this question but none of it is working.

I have an application consisting of a WordPress site at "domain.com", and a CakePHP/Angular application at "sub.domain.com".

I need my WordPress login cookie to be usable at "sub.domain.com".  I have read many things on this topic and everyone recommended I put in my `wp-config.php` file

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com');
```

This however is not redefining the domain for the cookie.

By contrast, as a test, in the Cake/Angular application, I manually defined a cookie in javascript at `.domain.com`, and when I go back to the WordPress site that cookie is available for use at both domain.com AND sub.domain.com.

What am I doing wrong that is causing WordPress to not redefine the cookie domain successfully?